# update react state for a single user details page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a user details page, and a user list page. simply you click on a link on the list page and this will render the users details on the bottom of the page. if you select another user, the component should be updated with the new data. it seems that react does not update the state, and the first select user's data is still visible.

```
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {}
    };
    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
  }

  getUser = id => {
    fetch("http://localhost:800/api/v1/users/" + id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ user: data }));
    console.log("testing");
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getUser(this.props.match.params.userId);
    window.state = this.state;
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>User Details</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="alert alert-light">
            <p>first name: {user.firstName}</p>
            <p>last name: {user.lastName}</p>
            <p>email: {user.email}</p>
            <p>birthday: {user.birthday}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userList: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ userList: data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Users</h2>
        {this.state.userList.map((user, key) => (
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/${user.id}`}>
                {user.firstName} {user.lastName}
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
        <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/:userId`} component={User} />
        <Route
          exact
          path={this.props.match.url}
          render={() => <h3>Select a User!</h3>}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is only called before the component is mounted, and a new `User` component is not mounted when the `userId` URL parameter change.

You could add a `componentDidUpdate` to your `User` component to fetch the new user when `userId` change.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if (prevProps.match.params.userId !== this.props.match.params.userId) {
    this.getUser(this.props.match.params.userId);
  }
}
```

Comment: the url gets changed as usual, but I can still that the component does not get updated with the new data received form the api.

Comment: @anyavacy Is the `componentDidUpdate` called? Can you `console.log` inside the if statement?

Comment: the issue now is that, the data is not shown anymore on the first click, and on page load ?

Comment: @anyavacy You still need the `componentDidMount` *and* `componentDidUpdate`.